# height 100% stopped working the same as before

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

i made a website some time ago link: https://randomchess.netlify.app and after that i forget about it and now when i opened it again, it was not working properly even though no changes have been made i soon get  to know it is happening because 100% height is not working as it was used to, i opened the website in chrome (linux version), the code is as follows

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.blur {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.board {
  height: 70%;
  display: grid;
}

#chessboard {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="vsc-initialized">
  <div class="blur">
    <section class="board" id="Board">
      <div id="chessboard">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is because of the display:gid. Try switching to display:flex

Comment: is it something new ? because as i mentioned it was working fine 5 months ago , and no changes have been made

Comment: Might be, Im not really into grid so I cant tell you the accurate reason, but I have poked around your site for a bit and this was the only part of your code that seemed to effect the functionality

Comment: the code you added works fine

Comment: then you can visit the side and change the flex to grid on the element with class board (since i have updated the website ) and check that it doesn't work

Comment: no, you need to provide a working code inside the question. As you said, you have updated the site which make this question useless since the code is not fixed and your link can break at any time in the future

Answer (score 0):

As i have checked your website, #board id you have added here and you have given padding 5%. so it will reduce the chessboard by 5% of it's total height and width. you should remove that padding, then it will work fine